# Underscorejs - Compare two arrays with objects

Tags: angularjs, underscore.js

I want to compare two arrays with objects with different key names using underscore...

```
array1 = [{email:"revosys@gmail.com", first_name:"asad"}, {email:"email1@gmail.com", first_name:"name1"}]

array2 = [{email2:"revosys@gmail.com", first_name2:"asad"}, {email2:"info@data.com", first_name2:"name22"}]
```

Want Output of unique email IDS from array2 which is NOT present in array1 like this...

```
array3 = [{email2:"info@data.com", first_name2:"name22"}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert `array1` to an object with the email addresses as keys, then filter array2 based on that:

```
var t = {};
angular.forEach(array1, function(v) { t[v.email] = 1 });
var array3 = array2.filter(
    function (v) {
       return angular.isUndefined(t[v.email2]);
    });
```

Sorry, `underscorejs` not needed here.

Or if you can use modern JS syntax it reads a bit more cleanly:

```
var t = {};
array1.forEach(v => t[v.email] = 1);
var array3 = array2.filter(v => angular.isUndefined(t[v.email2]));
```